# Error: (1) unstable-cluster in Aerospike how to resolve this issue

Tags: aerospike

I’m trying to setup aerospike DB clustering with 2 nodes using mesh concept, If 1 node is down, other node throwing unstable-cluster error.

How to solve this issue ?

```
select *from bar;
Error: (1) unstable-cluster
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the second node is constantly going in and out, the cluster is in a state of migration and you see this error because you are running essentially a scan job with select * . Once cluster state is stable, it will be back to giving you results.  See https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/cluster-error-1-unstable-cluster/6264/16  **AQL code sets fail_on_cluster_change to true in its configuration.**
You can test by setting this false, results are not reliable then.

```
aql> get FAIL_ON_CLUSTER_CHANGE
FAIL_ON_CLUSTER_CHANGE = true  <-- default
aql> set FAIL_ON_CLUSTER_CHANGE false
FAIL_ON_CLUSTER_CHANGE = false  <-- set it so and retest.  You may see node connection error then on the node that is dropping in and out.
```